# How to append data in to the dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
baseurl='https://twillmkt.com'
headers ={
    'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.114 Safari/537.36'
}
r =requests.get('https://twillmkt.com/collections/denim')
soup=BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')
tra = soup.find_all('div',class_='ProductItem__Wrapper')
productlinks=[]
for links in tra:
    for link in links.find_all('a',href=True):
        comp=baseurl+link['href']
        productlinks.append(comp)
temp=[]
for link in productlinks:
    r =requests.get(link,headers=headers)
    soup=BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')
    up = soup.find('div',class_='Product__SlideshowNavScroller')
    for pro in up:
        t=pro.find('img').get('src')
        print(t)
```

The code is working fine and give me the image link but I want give name `image1`,`image2` and so on  to get output like these as you seen in picture
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Note** *Main issue will be, that there is not the same count of images per page and you are calling the product pages mutliple times cause there are duplicates in your link list - Last could be avoided by `set()` the list*

One approache could be to append your data to a list of dicts to create a dataframe.

```
data.append({'id':t.split('=')[-1], 'image':'Image '+str(e)+' UI','link':t})
```

To get the modification you want use methods `pivot()` to transform and `fillna()` to generate empty cells, if there is no image source.

```
df.pivot(index='id', columns='image', values='link').reset_index().fillna('')
```

#### Example

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
baseurl='https://twillmkt.com'
headers ={
    'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.114 Safari/537.36'
}
r =requests.get('https://twillmkt.com/collections/denim')
soup=BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')
tra = soup.find_all('div',class_='ProductItem__Wrapper')
productlinks=[]
for links in tra:
    for link in links.find_all('a',href=True):
        comp=baseurl+link['href']
        productlinks.append(comp)

data = []

for link in set(productlinks):
    r =requests.get(link,headers=headers)
    soup=BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')
    up = soup.find('div',class_='Product__SlideshowNavScroller')
    for e,pro in enumerate(up):
        t=pro.find('img').get('src')
        data.append({'id':t.split('=')[-1], 'image':'Image '+str(e)+' UI','link':t})
        
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df.image=pd.Categorical(df.image,categories=df.image.unique(),ordered=True)
df = df.pivot(index='id', columns='image', values='link').reset_index().fillna('')
```

#### Output

| id | Image 0 UI | Image 1 UI | Image 2 UI | ... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1631812617 | //cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0089/7912/0206/products/Blue-Ripped-Knee-Distressed-Skinny-Denim_160x.jpg?v=1631812617 | //cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0089/7912/0206/products/Blue-Ripped-Knee-Distressed-Skinny-Denim-2_160x.jpg?v=1631812617 | //cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0089/7912/0206/products/Blue-Ripped-Knee-Distressed-Skinny-Denim-3_160x.jpg?v=1631812617 |  |
| 1631826938 | //cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0089/7912/0206/products/Light-Blue-Patch-Work-Stacked-Straight-Leg-Denim_160x.jpg?v=1631826938 | //cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0089/7912/0206/products/Light-Blue-Patch-Work-Stacked-Straight-Leg-Denim-2_160x.jpg?v=1631826938 | //cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0089/7912/0206/products/Light-Blue-Patch-Work-Stacked-Straight-Leg-Denim-3_160x.jpg?v=1631826938 |  |
| 1631829399 | //cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0089/7912/0206/products/Khaki-Patch-Work-Stacked-Straight-Leg-Denim_160x.jpg?v=1631829399 | //cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0089/7912/0206/products/Khaki-Patch-Work-Stacked-Straight-Leg-Denim-2_160x.jpg?v=1631829399 | //cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0089/7912/0206/products/Khaki-Patch-Work-Stacked-Straight-Leg-Denim-3_160x.jpg?v=1631829399 |  |
| ... |  |  |  |  |

Comment: if we only get `10 images ` how we can apply limit

Comment: Not sure what you mean  -  If you only wanna see 10 image columns from df --> `df.iloc[:,:12]`   -  if you  wanna limit the for loop --> `for e,pro in enumerate(up[:10]):`

*Each question should address exactly one problem, [a new question should be asked ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) for each additional problem.* Would be great - Thanks

Comment: I create new question kindly help in these https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70461816/they-show-me-error-index-contains-duplicate-entries-cannot-reshape

Comment: can you help me in these question?